# On the Divergence of $s_n=\cos{\frac{\pi}{3}n}$: A Proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality

Question:

> Show that $s_n=\cos{\frac{\pi}{3}n}$ is divergent.

Attempt:

> Suppose that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\cos{\frac{\pi}{3}n})=s$, then given an $\epsilon$, say $\epsilon=1$, we can find an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $$\begin{vmatrix} (\cos{\frac{\pi}{3}n})-s\end{vmatrix}<1.$$
>   If $n=6k+1$---for some sufficient $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then we obtain $\lvert \frac{1}{2}-s\rvert<1$, and so $\frac{1}{2}<s<\frac{3}{2}$; however, if $n=6k+3$---likewise for some sufficient $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then we obtain $\lvert -1-s\rvert<1$, and so $-2<s<0$. Therefore, since $s$ cannot satisfy both inequalities, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\cos{\frac{\pi}{3}n})$ does not exist

Comment: An easy way to handle the trig ones like this is find two explicit subsequences that have different limits.

Comment: You picked the wrong $\epsilon$ for your first choice of $n$, since the inequality is $-\frac{1}{2}\lt s\lt  \frac{3}{2}$ so there is overlap. It is in any case easier to use $n=6k$ and $n=6k+3$. With your choice, $\epsilon=\frac{1}{4}$ is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in your work.

However, as suggested above, an easier way is to just show that there are two subsequences converging to different limits.

In your case, $s_{6n+1}$ converges to $0.5$ and $s_{6n+3}$ converges to $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Should look something like this:

> Suppose that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\cos{\frac{\pi}{3}n})=s$, then given an $\epsilon$, say $\epsilon=\frac{1}{4}$, we can find an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $$\begin{vmatrix} (\cos{\frac{\pi}{3}n})-s\end{vmatrix}<1.$$
>   If $n=6k+1$---for some sufficient $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then we obtain $\lvert \frac{1}{2}-s\rvert<\frac{1}{4}$, and so $\frac{1}{4}<s<\frac{3}{4}$; however, if $n=6k+3$---likewise for some sufficient $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then we obtain $\lvert -1-s\rvert<\frac{1}{4}$, and so $-\frac{5}{4}<s<-\frac{3}{4}$. Therefore, since $s$ cannot satisfy both inequalities, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\cos{\frac{\pi}{3}n})$ does not exist

As was alluded to by A.N.